# rmsprop_v2 is not callable and i can't find the RMSprop optimizer? tensorflow v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

got this code

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import rmsprop_v2
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense, GRU, Embedding

model = Sequential()
optimizer = rmsprop_v2(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(loss=loss_mse_warmup, optimizer=optimizer)

model.summary()
```

but it keeps mentioning that the rmsprop_v2 is not callable, and i can't seem to find a way to import the "RMSprop" module

any idea on how to either import RMSprop, or make rmsprop_v2 work ?

tried to use RMSprop as the following show:
`tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.RMSprop`

Answer (score 0):

ended up fixing it by importing like this :

```
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop_v2
optimizer = rmsprop_v2.RMSprop()
Model.compile(loss='--',  optimizer=optimizer)
```